# Insert value from combo box to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my DB I have two tables (`Employee` and `Team`). The `Team` table has two columns (`ID`, `TeamName`) and it’s displayed in an asp.net page as a dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="team_id" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
```

From my asp.net page I need to insert a row into the employee table which includes `teamID`.

Below is set team combo box code

```
private void SetTeamComboBox()
    {
        DataTable tableVariable = GetTeam();
        team_id.DataTextField = "TEAMNAME";
        team_id.DataValueField = "ID";
        team_id.DataSource = tableVariable;

        //MANUALLY ADD ROW
        DataRow dr = tableVariable.NewRow();
        dr["TEAMNAME"] = "Select TEAM";
        dr["ID"] = 0;
        tableVariable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        team_id.SelectedIndex = 0;
        team_id.DataBind();
    }

public DataTable GetTeam()
    {
        SqlConnection oleconnectionVariable = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand commandVariable = new SqlCommand();
        commandVariable.CommandText = "SELECT ID,TEAMNAME FROM TEAM";
        commandVariable.Connection = oleconnectionVariable;
        oleconnectionVariable.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapterVariable = new SqlDataAdapter(commandVariable);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        adapterVariable.Fill(dataSet);

        adapterVariable.Dispose();
        commandVariable.Dispose();
        oleconnectionVariable.Dispose();
        return dataSet.Tables[0];//WE NEED TO GET THE DATATABLE  
    }
```

I need to insert the ID of the team but I’m getting an error on the following line.

```
commandVariable.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamID",Convert.ToInt32(team_id.SelectedValue));
```

team id is always ZERO (see debugging image below)

[image: Error image]

Comment: Are you sure your combobox is populated perfectly? what is the value that you are getting in `team_id.SelectedValue`

Comment: yes it's , and it's always 0

Comment: Can you post your insert code as well since your inserting the value?

Comment: insert code is working fine , my point is for team id it's always inserting zero which is wrong , it should be the ID for the team name.

Comment: Are you calling `SetTeamComboBox()` on the PostBack ? You may need to do this to repopulate the combo box, but it also sets `SelectedIndex` to 0.

Comment: it works with me after removing  DataRow dr = tableVariable.NewRow();
        dr["TEAMNAME"] = "Select TEAM";
        dr["ID"] = 0;
        tableVariable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        team_id.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: but i need to out value for index 0 like select team

Comment: No need to remove anythings just handled postback scenario which I already posted in as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are calling SetTeamComboBox() in Page_Load() event so every time DropDownBox control status changed. The problem in postback which not handled.

**Solution:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SetTeamComboBox();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Much appreciated , that was the issue exactly and you code solve it.

Comment: If you got your solution then close it with a click on sign icon.